# Авторизация без указания домена и redirect_url

Tags: vkontakte-api, авторизация

Есть ли возможность авторизации без указания ***redirect_url***, ***Домен***?

Например, если я хочу распростанять какой-то компонент **Joomla** или **Wordpress**, с возможностью авторизации через вк. Если я не знаю, какой у пользователя будет *домен* и *redirect_url*, то как правильно авторизовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если собираетесь проводить авторизацию через WEB приложения, то необходимо указать свой. Иначе вы ни как не сможете проверить, прошёл ли пользователь авторизацию и не отдаст `токен`.

Если же `DESKTOP`,то при настройке приложения  выбирайте тип `STANDALONE`.Авторизацию проводите через `IMPLICT FLOW AUTHORIZE` и шлите на URL `oauth.vk.com/blank.html`.Он проходит авторизацию и через программные решения забираете токен.